# pandas: replace string with another string

Tags: python, string, python-2.7, pandas, replace

I have the following data frame

```
    prod_type
0   responsive
1   responsive
2   respon
3   r
4   respon
5   r
6   responsive
```

I would like to replace `respon` and `r` with `responsive`, so the final data frame is

```
    prod_type
0   responsive
1   responsive
2   responsive
3   responsive
4   responsive
5   responsive
6   responsive
```

I tried the following but it did not work:

```
df['prod_type'] = df['prod_type'].replace({'respon' : 'responsvie'}, regex=True)
df['prod_type'] = df['prod_type'].replace({'r' : 'responsive'}, regex=True)
```

Answer (score 38, accepted):

Solution with [`replace`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.replace.html) by `dictionary`:

```
df['prod_type'] = df['prod_type'].replace({'respon':'responsive', 'r':'responsive'})
print (df)
    prod_type
0  responsive
1  responsive
2  responsive
3  responsive
4  responsive
5  responsive
6  responsive
```

If need set all values in column to some `string`:

```
df['prod_type'] = 'responsive'
```

Answer (score 5):

You don't need to pass `regex=True` here, as this will look for partial matches, as you''re after exact matches just pass the params as separate args:

```
In [7]:
df['prod_type'] = df['prod_type'].replace('respon' ,'responsvie')
df['prod_type'] = df['prod_type'].replace('r', 'responsive')
df

Out[7]:
    prod_type
0  responsive
1  responsive
2  responsvie
3  responsive
4  responsvie
5  responsive
6  responsive
```

Answer (score 3):

Other solution in case all items from `df['prod_type']` will be the same:

```
df['prod_type'] = ['responsive' for item in df['prod_type']]
In[0]: df
Out[0]:
prod_type
0  responsive
1  responsive
2  responsive
3  responsive
4  responsive
5  responsive
6  responsive
```

Answer (score 2):

alternatively, you can use apply function with lambda syntax

```
df['prod_type'] = df['prod_type'].apply(lambda x: x.replace('respon', 'responsvie'))
```

Answer (score 2):

Following up to jezrael's answer, you can set `inplace=True` to change the data frame:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(
    {'prod_type':['responsive','responsive','respon','r','respon','r','responsive']},
    columns=['prod_type'])

df.replace({'prod_type': {'respon': 'responsive', 'r': 'responsive'}}, inplace=True)
df
    prod_type
0  responsive
1  responsive
2  responsive
3  responsive
4  responsive
5  responsive
6  responsive
```