# Replace cells with specific terms

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I want to replace the words contains `"conference"` and `"group"` with `"N/A"` in the dataframe. 
*E.g. 
"AAAI Conference"->"N/A"   "Alibaba Group" -> "N/A"*

The dataframe is called `name`, I try two ways to do this:

```
columns=['nameCurrentEmployer',
       'name2ndEmployer', 'name3rdEmployer',
       'name4thEmployer', 'name5thEmployer',
       'name6thEmployer', 'name7thEmployer',
       'name8thEmployer', 'name9thEmployer',
       'name10thEmployer'] 
name.loc[name.str.contains(['conference','group'], case=False), columns] = 'N/A'
```

Prompt error *AttributeError: 'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'str'*

```
NAMES = pd.Series(name.values.flatten())
NAMES.loc[NAMES.str.contains(['conference','group'], case=False), columns] = 'N/A'
```

Now the error is

```
TypeError: unhashable type: 'list'
```

Thank you very much.

Comment: i'd suggest you use pandas str replace instead and possibly use a regex expression containing the words 'conference' or 'group'

Comment: What are you using the string _'N/A'_ for? Why are you doing _pd.Series(name.values.flatten())_ ? Can you share more of your program? Variable and function names should follow the `lower_case_with_underscores` style. Always share the **entire** error message. Do you not have a [mcve]?

Comment: Also, is this not just a worse duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39602824/pandas-replace-string-with-another-string ?

Comment: @ sammywemmy Thank you, str replace works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[`str.contains()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.contains.html) takes

> Character sequence or regular expression.

---

So instead of `['conference','group']` you should use `'conference|group'`:

```
NAMES.loc[NAMES.str.contains('conference|group', case=False), columns] = 'N/A'
```

---

Alternatively, I would suggest to use either `apply()`:

```
NAMES.name = NAMES.name.apply(lambda x: 'N/A' if 'conference' in x else x)
```

or [`str.replace()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.replace.html)

Comment: Thank you, Giorgos. But it still prompts two errors:                                             
1.TypeError: 'Series' objects are mutable, thus they cannot be hashed  2.Indexing Error      How should I fix it or is there any other way that can do the same job?                             Thanks again.

Comment: Why not recommend the use of [`DataFrame.replace`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.replace.html#pandas-dataframe-replace), instead of the needlessly awkward `.loc[]` method?

Comment: @RenzhiZhao Can you address the points made by the first commenter and myself?

Comment: @ AMC Thank you, AMC. Replace works. You really help me out and give me a good lesson about raising good questions.